# WDK toolset not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, wdk

I am trying to compile a sample of WDK7.1 with Visual Studio 2012 and I get this error:

> Error 1   error MSB8020: The builds tools for
>   WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1 (Platform Toolset =
>   'WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1') cannot be found. To build using the
>   WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1 build tools, either click the Project
>   menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++
>   Projects...". Install WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1 to build using
>   the WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1 build tools.  OEMUNI  C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets  44  5

I have tried reinstalling the WDK but nothing changed.
Any idea what I should do?

Comment: which sample? Possibly you need VS2013, as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869136/the-builds-tools-for-windowskernelmodedriver8-1-platform-toolset-windowskern

Comment: I try to compile "oemuni". The link you posted doesn't exist anymore. I don't know if it is madatory to install WDK on C:. I put it on another partition because I am misssing free space.

Comment: link contains a deleted question - anyway can't find the sample for WDK 7.1, please provide a linke. Aslo you are sure you are not using http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/OEMDLL-Samples-71364d95 as that requires VS2013?

Comment: Hm.. Yes! I probably use a project from this url. The one in my WDK7.1 directory seems to miss a project and a solution file and I don't remember myself creating one for it. So, probably that's it. Thanks. I wonder how I will manage to setup a project (with all the settings) for this myself...

Comment: I would guess you need to set a different toolset, no idea which one though

Comment: I think it is WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1 again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454232(v=vs.85).aspx I will try it and see what happens.